# In which Christian groups is "prosperity theology" derogatory?

Tags: denomination-survey, pentecostalism, prosperity-gospel

What Christian denomination(s) believe(s) that "prosperity theology" is derogatory, and why? What are the justifications against prosperity theology?

I know that some neo-Pentecostal churches preach prosperity theology, and they preach it, considering the socioeconomic status of their members, providing social services and stuff like that. Doesn't Jesus want Christians to be happy and healthy?

Comment: I think "prosperity theology" has to do with believing that God will give you whatever you ask for if you have enough faith. The way the worst of these people teach, God is almost obligated to give you what you say you want.

Comment: @mojo Imagine yourself living in a shabby home in Africa for a moment and walking into a beautiful church building with nicely polished floors and state-of-the-art air conditioning. In this context, prosperity theology may not be so bad.

Comment: It boils down to idolatry.

Comment: Here's a [United Methodist response to prosperity theology](http://gbgm-umc.org/global_news/full_article.cfm?articleid=3258).

Comment: And here's a [response from a Baptist scholar](http://www.patheos.com/blogs/rogereolson/2012/02/is-the-prosperity-gospel-heresy/).

Comment: [John Piper on why he hates the prosperity gospel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PTc_FoELt8s) "God is most glorified in you when you are most satisfied in him *in the midst of loss* not prosperity."

Comment: I've heard that the Lord changes the hearts of men from the inside. Then those men have power to change their lives from the outside through honest hard work.

Comment: Although this is not from a Pentacostal church. The Book of Mormon a scripture of the LDS church says that the Lord said that ["Inasmuch as ye shall keep my commandments ye shall prosper in the land."](https://www.lds.org/scriptures/bofm/2-ne/4.4?lang=eng#3)

Comment: I realized that I misunderstood your question. Your asking about which churches teach against "prosperity theology".

Comment: @Anonymous, imagine yourself living in a shabby home in Africa for a moment, and seeing a rich-looking pastor on the television inviting you to just have faith and you will be rich too: you just have to spend all your money on his books which explain how in 10 easy steps. He gets to build his beautiful church building with nicely polished floors and state-of-the-art air conditioning. And you stay in your shabby home.

Comment: That aside, this questions is badly phrased. You would be better asking which groups actually believe in prosperity theology, because the list is (comparatively) very small. Also, your last sentence is a different question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are several denominations that do not believe in a Prosperity Theology. I can speak from a Baptist perspective. The primary reason to disagree is the idea of following a prescribed set of rules leads to automatic financial blessing from God. I have heard this described as a "vending machine" concept of God - if I put certain things in, God will give me other things in return.

But God works his will, not ours. If our will is in alignment with His, then we are in the best place we can be, but that is not a guarantee of any particular type of blessing. The only blessing that can be guaranteed is salvation to those who believe.

Many of the patriarchs were wealthy, but many of the disciples were not. Are we to believe that they were unfaithful?